# Why is this method of counting Mysql rows using PDO not working?

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, count

I am attempting to count the rows returned from a `SELECT` statement using PDO.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat_id= ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$cat_id);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$count_posts = count($rows);
return $count_posts;
```

I use `fetchAll()` and then `count()` to count but it doesn't work. When I echo this out it echos `0`. I thought the array was `$rows` and that `$count_posts` would then be the count of that array?

`echo $count_posts = count_cat_posts($cat_id);`

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but that's basic debugging. You cannot just `echo` an array to inspect it. You need a loop, or `print_r()`, or `var_dump()`. Additionally, how do you verify whether `prepare()`, `bindParam()` and `execute()` succeed and see error messages otherwise?

Comment: I thought i was counting the array first then echoing the count?

Comment: @Amir I'm not using rowCount() in this instance, but thanks

Comment: @crm..sorry it was my mistake to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This method should **never** be used to count rows in the database. It's ok if you need to use all these rows later, and want just count them first. But never use it only to count.
2. One have to select **the very data they need** and nothing else. If you need a row count - select a row count then,

   ```
   SELECT  count(1) FROM posts WHERE cat_id= ?
   ```

   and then fetch that number using `fetchColumn()`
3. As for the particular error in your code - it seems just a silly typo. Most likely you're echoing out not the $count_posts but $rows instead (judging by the word `Array` you mentioned).
4. Well it's always amazing to see the essential part of the question edited after you wrote an answer.
   If you have 0 as a count - either there is no rows under selected category, or whatever **another** typo-like mistake
5. Anyway, you shouldn't select all the table data to get count only

Comment: Thanks, no typos. When echoing it shows `0` not array, my bad.

Comment: .4 Your right, I forgot to assign a value to `$cat_id` Thanks

Comment: `fetchall` returns an array containing all result rows and `count()` ,count all elements in an array... then why it does not work?